# finding the parent directory in a url and comparing to navigation urls

Tags: php, jquery, url, navigation

basically I have a navigation menu, currently if I go to a page on the site it adds 'current' class to the navigation menu item so I can change it's style. Like so:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
    var path = window.location;
    $('#nav a[href="'+path+'"]').addClass('current');
});
```

I want to extend this to include any page under it. I have come across a few posts explaining how you do it but non seem to work for me. The URLs are quite long, and the site heavily relays on parameters in the url so a type url might be example.com/path1/path2/?id=9238293&name=test.

Not sure if jquery is the best way to do this? Open to doing it in PHP also if possible.

Comment: how can you know if a page is "under" another one ? (by looking at the url)

Comment: How do you build your menu? is it built with PHP or just a static block of html? Can you show your code

Answer (score 0):

YOu can have this in PHP:

```
<?php
       //$url =  'http://example.com/path1/path2/?id=9238293&name=test';
       $url = $_POST['path'];

       //REMOVE THE LAST PARAMETER IN URL ?id=9238293&name=test';
       $paths = explode('?',$url);

       $paths = count($paths) ? $paths[0] : $paths; //if have parameter or not

       $paths = explode('/', $paths); //SEPARATE THE URL
       if (!$paths[count($paths)-1]){
         unset($paths[count($paths)-1]); //VERIFY IF THE URL ENDS WITH '/'
       }

       $count = count($paths);
       //THEN YOU HAVE
       //YOUR CURRENT PAGE
       //print "Current page: ".$paths[$count-1];
       //print "Mother page: ".$paths[$count-2];
       //THEN YOU CAN COMPARE THE MOTHER PAGE WITH ONE EXISTING MENU PAGE

       //IN YOUR EXAMPLE YOU CAN GO:
       $return = array();
       $site = "http://example.com/";
       $current = $paths[$count-1];
       $mother = $paths[$count-2];
       $return['current'] = $site.$mother.'/'.$current; //THAT WAY YOU STRIP THE PARAMETERS TO GET THIS ON YOUR JAVASCRIPT
       $return['mother'] = $site.$mother;
       print json_encode($return);exit;
?>
```

Then in your client-side do:

```
<script>
    jQuery(document).ready(function($){
        var path = window.location;
        //very important!
        path = path.toString();
        $.post('YOUR PHP SCRIPT URL',{path:path},function(data){
                $('#nav a[href="'+data.current+'"]').addClass('current');
                $('#nav a[href="'+data.mother+'"]').addClass('current');
        },'json');      
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for this, makes sense, but little confused with 'your php script url' do you mean I do a include_once seems to prevent page from loading, though not throwing any obvious error

Comment: Didn't understand what have you said! What did you meant with "do you mean I do a include_once seems to prevent page from loading, though not throwing any obvious error ". hehe